# http://example.com/fruits/apple I want to redirect to http://example.com/pen/apple

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes

I working in zend 1 and I want to do this. If anybody call http://example.com/fruits/apple, then I want to redirect to http://example.com/pen/apple.
I am already using this code to perform this.

```
resources.router.routes.pen.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static"
resources.router.routes.pen.route = "pen/apple"
resources.router.routes.pen.defaults.controller = "fruits"
resources.router.routes.pen.defaults.action = "apple"
```

But if I have 20 actions, then I need to do this for all actions. 
I want a single code to redirect to another controller with the same action in Zend Framework 1.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this result you should write a Action Plugin, then register it.

Plugin will run for each request and you can attach your functionality at a specific point in the dispatch process, here's the doc https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.controller.plugins.html .

The strategy you should use is at pre dispatch, check the controller within the current request and if the controller is 'fruit' change it with 'pen'.